# Google Sheet IMPORTXLM All Time High On CoinMarketCap

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I have been trying to import the all-time high on coinmarketcap.com but I keep getting an empty cell.

It works for getting the price by using

base_url = https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/

x_path = `//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span`

bitcoin

```
=IMPORTXLM(base_url & bitcoin, x_path)
```

ps: I use "&", so whenever I change the cell text from bitcoin to any other coin it can work automatically.

But when I do copy the XPath for all time high it doesn't work. Any tips?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXRtF.png)

Comment: can you screenshot the value you trying to get?

Comment: This is my first time using stack overflow, but I just added it to the post. It says "enter image description here" lol